# Emacs truncate lines in all buffers

Tags: emacs, elisp

What can I put in my .emacs file so that all lines an any kind of buffer always truncate if too long. I do this mostly because I tend to open many frames and it gets hard to read on a small screen if my 80 char lines get wrapped 2 or 3 times over.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try `M-x` `toggle-truncate-lines` on a per buffer basis, to see if it does what you want.

In `.emacs` you'd put this, to make it default for all buffers.

```
(setq-default truncate-lines t)
```

You may also like:

```
(setq-default global-visual-line-mode t)
```

Which you can try out with `M-x` `visual-line-mode` (it also toggles.)

<sup>EmacsWiki references: [`visual-line-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VisualLineMode) [`truncate-lines`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TruncateLines)</sup>

Comment: So I guess (setq 'global-visual-line-mode t) ?

Comment: It's odd since I thought I tried truncate-lines before to no avail maybe I messed something up, thanks :)

Comment: Yeah it worked now, I tried virtual lines instead but I would just rather have them truncated but thanks for the wiki references on both.

Comment: `(global-visual-line-mode 1) ; 1 for on, 0 for off.`

Comment: I don't know why but `(setq-default truncate-lines t)` does not work on my case. but `M-x toggle-truncate-lines` works. @ocodo

Comment: @alper - try this question on https://emacs.stackexchange.com too (https://emacs.stackexchange.com/search?q=truncate-lines)

Comment: `(setq-default truncate-lines t)` didn't work on my case @ocodo

Comment: As others have indicated, `(setq-default truncate-lines t)` does not work.

Answer (score 2):

In your `.emacs` or `.emacs.el` or `.emacs.d/init.el` (depends where you locate your main emacs config file), write :

```
(custom-set-variables
  '(truncate-lines t))
```

the block `custom-set-variables` may already exist, so just add `'(truncate-lines t)` to the list. This way your configuration file keeps clean.

Alternatively you could hook a keybinding, like that :

```
(local-set-key (kbd "C-x w") 'toggle-truncate-lines)
```

So you can truncate when the lines are bothering the visual

Comment: `(global-set-key "\C-x\ w" 'toggle-truncate-lines)` also works.

Comment: Like the accepted answer, the solution `(custom-set-variables '(truncate-lines t))` in this answer does not work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

If the `(setq-default truncate-lines t)` didn't work, it's possible that you are in another major mode, ie markdown-mode, etc.  In that case, this worked for me.  (I tested it on Emacs v28.1 / Doom Emacs on Mac)

```lisp
;; in init.el, etc...
;; word-wrapping off
(setq-default truncate-lines t)
;; for markdown-mode
(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook (lambda () (setq truncate-lines t)))
```